# Dynamic values for an external variable in C

Tags: c, global, extern

I have file.h:

```
extern int global_value;
```

and file1.c:

```
#include "file.h"
int global_value = 0;
main()
{
   while(1)
      global_value++;
}
```

and file2.c:

```
#include "file.h"
main()
{
   while(1)
      printf("%d", global_value);
}
```

My problem is that the value on the display is always 0.
Where is the problem?

Comment: You have 2 main functions. Are you running two separate programs? By the way it must be `int main()`; if your compiler doesn't complain throw it away and get a decent free one.

Comment: Please don't post live-code examples on Stack Overflow. Instead, re-write a self-containing and reduced code example from scratch that reproduces exactly the problem you want to ask about. Everything else is too broad. Also restrain from debugging requests and personal tutoring requests here on Stack Overflow. All you need to do is to formulate a concrete programming question, that's your entry-card.

Comment: You mistyped "gloabal_value"

Comment: Perhaps "file2.h" should be "file2.c"?  If so, please edit the question and fix this (and perhaps other things)?

Comment: yes I have 2 sepate program

Comment: sorry, I typped wrongly file2.h, it's file2.c and gloabl_value is global_value

Comment: `file2.h` (you mean, `.c`?) should not pass linking. Either linker will complain about duplicate symbol `main`, or linker will complain about undefined symbol `global_value`.

Comment: Two separate programs will possess two separate copies of `global_value`.

Comment: is there any other idea to change value content on one separate program and read it in other in C language?

Comment: Look up Shared Memory, or IPC, or named pipes, or sockets, or memory mapped files or ...

Comment: Also, enable and fix warnings!. For *gcc* and *clang* it's command line switches `-Wall -Wextra`, and for Visual C it's `/W3`.

Answer (score 2):

Global variables have a limited scope which does not extend beyond the current executable.

Comment: You can not share a variable between two executables simply by declaring it in both programs.

Comment: Perhaps the value could be stored in a file where both could access it; or (much more advanced) the two executables might have a shared memory space.  In both cases, the shared resource might need to be protected with some sort of semaphore to avoid data corruption.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I find it, I use the IPC shared memory and it works correctly